# Mockmvc for a DELETE method that accepts a Multipart file

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockmvc

I'm trying to write a unit test for a controller that has a *DELETE* method that should accept a File and a text param.

I know I can do a simple delete like that:

```
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete(
            "/deletecat/catname/Oscar"))
            .andExpect(status().isOK)
            .andReturn();
```

And I can do a POST to a Multipart file like that:

```
MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", new FileInputStream(TEST_RESOURCES_FOLDER + "Cats.csv"));
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/uploadcats")
   .file(multipartFile)
   .param("ownerName", "Austin Powers"))
   .andExpect(status().isOk())
   .andReturn();
```

But when I tried to combine them together and wrote this:

```
 MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete(
                    "/deletecats", 
                    multipartFile, "Austin Powers"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
```

I get the following error of **"Current request is not a multipart request"**:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
```

Is it possible that the HTTP protocol is not supporting to do a DELETE with Multipart file?

Comment: Aren't you trying to do something that should not be done? I think your test shows that your API is wrong because, if I recall correctly, DELETE should not have BODY. If I am wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder` only supports `POST` requests, the constant representing HTTP method [is hard-coded in the constructors](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/8aa6e5bfea2c7314deaa1b432554e9e914b09ee7/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder.java#L61). This is strange because at least `POST` and `PUT` are commonly used with multipart.

I'm afraid that with current version you would have to fork the class and change the HTTP method yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would say that this is wrong from API design perspective.

REST is heavily working with resources and therefore with their dedicated identifiers e.g.

get /entities for getting a list of entities
get /entities/{entity-id} for getting a single entity

same pattern I would apply for delete: Adressing the resource by identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring 5.3.21 you can use `MockMvcRequestBuilders#multipart(HttpMethod httpMethod, String urlTemplate)` or `MockMvcRequestBuilders#multipart(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri)` to create a request that contains the required file and calls any of the available HTTP methods. For example:

```
    MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "file".getBytes());
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/deletecats")
   .file(multipartFile)
   .param("ownerName", "Austin Powers"))
   .andExpect(status().isOk())
   .andReturn();
```

You can read more about the metods here: [https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/.../MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#multipart...](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#multipart(org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))